# POSTMAN Pre-Request Script Need Actual Body for Hashmac calculation

Tags: postman

I have googled and looked for this answer but been unable to find what I need

During the pre-request script I do a hashmac calculation which requires the body to actually match what postman sends.

This is normally fine until people start using enviroment variables and comments in their json body’s.

I can easily fix the json body for enviroment variables using

```
requestBody = pm.variables.replaceIn(requestBody);
hashedPayload = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(requestBody)));


// I then set the Enviroment header for the hashmac
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('hmacAuthHeader', getAuthHeader(request['method'], requestUrl, request['data']));
```

However comments seem to be a bit more tricky.

I am wondering if anyone knows how to get the actual request body that gets sent in a post after it has had all the comments and enviroment variables replaced and removed during a pre-request script.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Comment: You have a request, and you want to know upfront, int the pre-request script of that request, what request body will be send?

Comment: Yes in the pre-request script for postman we have "pm.request.body", but this is not what postman actual sends once its sent. They apply some transformations, such as replacing the variables and removing comments from the json body. I want the body of the request after the transformations have been applied but have not found a way to get that, Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postman provided answer here: https://community.postman.com/t/pre-request-script-need-actual-body-for-hashmac-calculation/57022/6
I used:

```
 var requestBody =  pm.request.body.toString();
 // We need to ensure that all variables are 
 //replaced before we hash the values otherwise they wont match
 requestBody = pm.variables.replaceIn(requestBody);
 // Strip JSON Comments
 if (pm.request.body.mode === 'raw') {
        requestBody = requestBody.replace(/\\"|"(?:\\"|[^"])*"|(\/\/.*|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)/g, (m, g) => g ? "" : m)
        pm.request.body.raw = requestBody;
        pm.request.headers.add({key: 'Content-Type', value: 'application/json'});
    }
    

const hashedPayload = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(requestBody)));
```